# Передача данных из базы SQLite в Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Всем привет. С sqlite работаю недавно. Мне нужно сделать следующее. Есть база данных, всю информацию из нее я хочу передать в Recyclerview, как это сделать?
Как размышляю на данный момент. Хочу каждую строку преобразовать в объект, а объекты эти будут находиться в List и уже из него раскидывать значения по вьюшкам.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать и вообще правильно ли я размышляю?
Спасибо!

Comment: Создаете любую из реализаций `List<>` и передаете в адаптер, который использует все полученные данные для создания `View`. _"Хочу каждую строку преобразовать в объект, а объекты эти будут находиться в `List` и уже из него раскидывать значения по вьюшкам."_. Все правильно. Проще говоря, алгоритм такой: читаете строку- создаете объект- добавляете в массив- передаете массив в адаптер- реализуете использование данных для заполнения `View`

Comment: все неправильно. Такая реализация будет сильно расходовать память и отнимать много времени при старте списка. Правильно -
 получить из БД курсор (экземпляр класса Cursor) и использовать для списка любую реализацию адаптера, который работает с курсором напрямую, собственную или уже готовую (на гитхаб [множество реализаций](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=recyclerview+cursor&type=)). Для подгрузки данных использовать `CursorLoader`.

Comment: Если хотите работать с объектами посмотрите в сторону [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/). Данная БД так же имеет [собственный адаптер](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#adapters) для `RecyclerView`